# Tomcat graceful undeploy

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I haven't found documentation confirming that the undeploy action from Tomcat Manager is a graceful undeploy (that is, it finishes serving current requests). Can someone more knowledgeable confirm that this is indeed the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, undeploy is graceful as long as the requests finish in a timely manner (the default is 10 seconds but is configurable).

Requests that go beyond 10 seconds will finish cleanly unless they try to load a resource (class, static file, etc.) after the 10 seconds have passed. In that case they will fail with a ClassNotFoundException or similar.

Comment: do you have reference?